# I want to create a set of data frames from a data frame

Tags: r

Seems to me this should be really simple but....

```
     a <- 5
     b <- 1:a
     c <- matrix(rnorm(30, 1), ncol = 5)
     out <- lapply(c,c[,i])

    Error in c[, i] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I want to break the data frame into its columns and have a set of new data smaller frames, one  for each column

I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Help is always very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?  I think you just need to define an anonymous function in your lappy call

```
 a <- 5
 b <- 1:a
 c <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30, 1), ncol = 5))
 out <- lapply(c, function(i) data.frame(i))
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you want to break a data frame up into multiple data frames, one for each column. Are you sure you want to do this? There's a lot of questions where people want to know how to loop over a bunch of objects, when they'd be better served wrapping all those objects into a list or similar data structure. Note that a data frame is basically just a list of columns.

With that out of the way....

```
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), ncol=5))
for(i in seq_len(ncol(d))) {
    name <- names(d)[i]
    assign(name, d[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you for the comment and I will think that over carefully because I think you are right. Code works but I still end up with a matrix that has five columns.I didn't explain properly what I needed I guess.

Comment: Fixed a couple of glitches. Also, this will actually save the columns as vectors, not data frames as such.